# Check if a geo location falls within two geo locations

Tags: ios, objective-c, geolocation, coordinates

So,I'm trying to create an applications, where the user sets his destination on a map - let's say from Home to work-, then (with the help of google maps)a direction line shows on the map to guide the user to his destination, or to work in our example . 
What I'm trying to achieve here is that I want the app to show any coffee house that is going to be on the user's way to work,or slightly around it, but I'm not sure how to tackle this head scratcher .

Is there a way to know if a point (C) , falls within a straight line between A and b ? or falls close by factor(x) to the line between A and B ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/mayrestinpeace/49fc6d241524f0d948e4912f743d6350) which is a **Swift** translation of `locationIndexOnEdgeOrPath` function and all the other required functions present in [PolyUtil.java](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.java#L224).

The parameters you need to pass are the co-ordinates of the point you want to check and the array of points that represent the path. (Your case only includes start and end point, so just pass those two)

The other parameters needed are `closed` which represents whether a line should be drawn from the last point to first point in order to close the loop; `geodesic` which means if the earth's curvature should be taken into consideration.

Finally, `toleranceEarth` is the last parameter where you need to specify how *close* to the path is considered being *on the path*.

Comment: seems really interesting !! lemme give it a try and get back to you ! 
Thanks :)